# In Google Sheets,how to get a value lower than a particular cell value in a row?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-custom-function

In Google Sheets, I have numbers in 12 cells in a row. Then in the 13th cell of the same row, I have a number which is one of these 12 numbers. Now, I want find the 1st value lower than the value in the 13th cell going from right to left. Example:

2020    2090    2201    2393    2273    **2159**    2105    2200    2150    2199    2225    2290 **2159**

2159 is 13th cell value, which is in the 6th cell and the 1st lower value before that is 2090. I want this value in a cell in that row. The 13th cell value can be any of the 1st 12 cell values (not necessarily in 6th cell).

Comment: Did you try `=MINIFS()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=max(filter(INDIRECT("A6:"&ADDRESS(MATCH(M6,A6:L6,0),row(M6)-1, 4)),INDIRECT("A6:"&ADDRESS(MATCH(M6,A6:L6,0),row(M6)-1, 4))<M6))`

(assumes that the data is on row#6)

The logical sequence is:

- `match` - match the value in column M with the range of 12 columns to the left (A:L). This returns the column number.
- `address` - build the cell address for the matching value, but use the column one cell to the left (this will become the right-hand end of a range).
- `indirect` - return the range values from cell A6 to the "address"
- `filter` - filter the range, and set the condition for range values less than the value in column M
- `max` - return the maximum value of the remaining values.